# Center 3rd div beneath 2 others?

Tags: css

Trying to position one div beneath 2 others, while keeping all 3 centered.
Have tried different floats and clears, but just can't get it.

https://codepen.io/Aandr3w/pen/XWjPYjy
[image]

HTML

```
<div id="block-left" style="border: 1px solid purple;">
  <ul>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Mouse</li>
  <li>Bear</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="block-center">
<div style="border: 1px solid red; float: left;">
  <ul>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Mouse</li>
  <li>Bear</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; float: left;">
  <ul>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Mouse</li>
  <li>Bear</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world </div>
</div>

<div id="block-right" style="border: 1px solid yellow;">
  <ul>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Mouse</li>
  <li>Bear</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #699;
}

#block-left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#block-center {
    position: fixed;
/*  
    display: inline-block;
*/
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#block-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 90%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more `div` around your lists and this has to be styled with `display:flex` and `justify-content:center`:

```
div id="block-center">
  <div style="display:flex;justify-content: center;">
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <ul>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Mouse</li>
  <li>Bear</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
  <ul>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Mouse</li>
  <li>Bear</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  </ul>
  </div></div>
  <div style="clear:both;">hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world </div>
</div>
```